# Query - Receipt of Online payment from USA customer to Account in United Kingdoms

Tags: international-transfer, online-banking

I received payments from a USA customer in UK Account. All is doing well till start of 2019.

In 2019 the customer from USA intimated that he has submitted an online check to our account in UK but the check return.

What information/document may I ask from customer about release of payment so that bottlenecks could be removed.

Hussain

Comment: As I understand it, it would NOT in any way be possible to use an "online cheque", from the USA, to pay someone in the UK.  They would have to just use what everyone uses, either OFX or Transferwise, or, just use an ordinary old-fashioned "bank wire" (which costs 30 or 40 bucks, but that's life).

Comment: During this our bank in UK changed its correspondent bank. Has this some problem?

Comment: yes, it's a disaster.  you have to give the *new* wire transfer information to your customer.  however as I say, it is much easier for them to use ofx.com or transferwise.com

Comment: What is difference among   Intl-Wire Domestic to foreign / ACH Domestic to Domestics /  IAT Domestic to Domestics